# angular.js + require.js + multipage seed

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

So, I think these 2 seeds are awsome:

- https://github.com/tnajdek/angular-requirejs-seed
- and https://github.com/simonsmith/modular-html-requirejs

But, is there one combining the both practices? That is; is there a seed for a multipage angular app (as opposed to single page) that uses require.js? If not, how would you go about integrating the two above?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I've spend half my day figuring this out, as my own solution to it randomly loads the angular controller too late, so I get an 'Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'AppController' is not a function, got undefined' half the time I request the page, while the other half works just fine. Every example I've found about using angular with require.js have been for SPAs.

Comment: @Impero no, I opted out and when for a simpler solution. I seperated all my Models (classes with validation logic) to use require.js and in my main.js file I'm appending all models to a global variable MODELS. Then I have a small setTimeout-loop that checks for window["MODELS"] to be present and when it is it bootstraps angular. Also I wrap all classes in MODELS as angular factories. In this way I can have a Model-layer with AMD which is 100% reusable at serverside (node.js) and not having to mix angular and require.js which seems like it would cause pain since not many people are doing so...

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution for angular+ require + grunt + karma project. 
You can just start with it and use consept in your project.

https://github.com/azadorozhniy/kickstart_angular